# Error in TikZ pgfplots with timestamps on axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, dateplot

I get the following error message when I try to compile the attached code. I tried everything, but can't find the error.

```
Runaway argument?
\pgfplots@calender@ZEROSHIFT \relax \ifx \pgfplotstemptime \pgfutil@empty \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfcalendar@datetojulian.
 <inserted text> 
                \par
```

Here's an example document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xticklabel={\hour:\minute:\second},
date coordinates in=x,
xticklabel style= {rotate=45,anchor=north east},
xtick={
    {07/01/2013 04:00:00}
    {07/01/2013 05:00:00}
},
xmin={07/01/2013 04:00:00},
xmax ={07/01/2013 05:00:00},
clip = false,
xlabel=Date and time,
ylabel=physical storage]
\addplot plot coordinates {
    (07/01/2013 04:42:45, 4096.0)
    (07/01/2013 04:45:45, 6144.0)
    (07/01/2013 04:49:45, 8192.0)
    (07/01/2013 04:52:45, 8192.0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to use `-` instead of `/` and there is a missing `,` between the two xticks. It is also better to add a `date ZERO` specification in the axis environment like this `date ZERO={07/01/2013}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dashes instead of slashes compile without errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xticklabel=\hour:\minute:\second,
date coordinates in=x,
xticklabel style= {rotate=45,anchor=north east},
xtick={
    {07-01-2013 04:00:00},
    {07-01-2013 05:00:00}
},
xmin={07-01-2013 04:00:00},
xmax ={07-01-2013 05:00:00},
clip = false,
xlabel=Date and time,
ylabel=physical storage
]
\addplot coordinates {%
(07-01-2013 04:42:45, 4096.0)
(07-01-2013 04:45:45, 6144.0)
(07-01-2013 04:49:45, 8192.0)
(07-01-2013 04:52:45, 8192.0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out, that the / are ok inside the timestamps as well. The problem was the curling brackets in xticklabel, which you have removed. Thx!

Comment: @Tobi Wow did I? That was pure luck. Sorry :)